# Read and convert custom datetime format of CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

The real datetime in file.csv is: `2018/1/2  8:30:00.4 AM`.
However, the custom format of date is: `mm:ss.0`
Then the datetime in CSV would be: 30.00.4
In python, `df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')`
This value would be read as `30.00.4` instead of `2018/1/2 8:30:00.4`.
How can I get the whole datetime?

The data in CSV is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRdSk.png), and in custom format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOzyS.png)

After read CSV in python, it cannot show the whole datetime

Comment: Can you confirm the whole date format used in `file.csv`   e.g.`YYYY/MM/DD  hh:mm:ss.tenths AM/PM` ?

Comment: The format in file.csv is  mm:ss.0 only.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show a few example lines from `file.csv` and what your expected output would be. This would help me to understand better.

Comment: If data in your CSV includes only time, where you get correct date? Another field in the same CSV or somewhere else?